# error: <identifier> expecte when setting up binding adapters for two way data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to setup two way binding for `TextInputEditText` with `Float` variable.

Here is the entire content of my DataBindingAdapters class.

```
object DataBindingAdapters  {
    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setText(view: TextInputEditText, value: Float) {
        if(value != view.text.toString().toFloat()) {
            view.setText(value.toString())
        }
    }


    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    fun getText(view: TextInputEditText): Float  {

        return view.text.toString().toFloat()
    }

}
```

But I am getting:

```
error: <identifier> expected
            float callbackArg_0 = mBindingComponent.null.getText(inputFieldSize);
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Are you trying to set `LiveData<Float>` object on `android:text` in UI via Two-way Binding? If yes then I would suggest to make those `Float` parameters nullable on both methods.

Comment: did you find a solution already?

Comment: @LMaker no. Just used strings for the bindings....

Comment: Have you solved it? how?

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass I bypassed the issue altogether by using string for the bindings and converting when saving. It wasn't worth it. And now I've moved on to Compose :)

Answer (score 3):

You miss one more binding adapter, as mentioned in the [InverseBindingAdapter documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter):

```
@BindingAdapter(value = [ "android:textAttrChanged"], requireAll = false)
fun setTextWatcher( view: TextInputEditText, textAttrChanged: InverseBindingListener?) {
    val newValue =  object: TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) = Unit

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit

        override fun onTextChanged( s:CharSequence,  start:Int,  before:Int,  count:Int) {
                textAttrChanged?.onChange()
        }
    }

    val  oldValue = ListenerUtil.trackListener(view, newValue, R.id.textWatcher)
    if (oldValue != null) {
        view.removeTextChangedListener(oldValue)
    }
    view.addTextChangedListener(newValue)
}
```

When you create `@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")`, an event `android:textAttrChanged` is created, and you have to add a binding adapter for it.

Calling `textAttrChanged?.onChange()` will trigger the `InverseBindingAdapter` that you created.

EDIT:

Also, you are using Kotlin so you don't need to put your binding adapters in an `object`. A separate file will suffice. Just remove wrapping `object DataBindingAdapters  {..}` and `@JvmStatic` and you should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I am getting the same errors.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel How did you solved it?

Comment: @WilliamHu I bypassed the issue altogether by using string for the bindings and converting when saving. It wasn't worth it. And now I've moved on to Compose :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by making the inverse binding adapter static like in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-custom-attrs):

```
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    @JvmStatic fun getText(view: TextInputEditText): Float  {

        return view.text.toString().toFloat()
    }
```

Note the `@JvmStatic` right before `fun getText(...`. This is the only change from the code in your question.

BTW: [Mohru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61309889/398844) also mentions this in the edit-section, but at least for me it was not obvious enough to be found in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue,

the fix is:

```
class MyView {
  companion object {
     @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setText(view: TextInputEditText, value: Float) {
        if(value != view.text.toString().toFloat()) {
            view.setText(value.toString())
        }
    }


    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    fun getText(view: TextInputEditText): Float  {

        return view.text.toString().toFloat()
    }
  }
}
```

Besides this, you may/have to add `textAttrChanged` event also. If it needs then it will tell you `xxx: textAttrChanged not found......` error. Then add below method just side the `companion object` body

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["android:textAttrChanged"], requireAll = false)
        @JvmStatic fun setValue(view: MyView, textAttrChanged: InverseBindingListener) {
            val newValue = object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                    textAttrChanged.onChange()
                }
            }
            view.binding.editText.addTextChangedListener(newValue)
        }
```

Besides this, you might get warnings in above code.

Then you can use:

```
object XXXAdapter {
   //Put the binding methods here.
}
```

to silence the warnings.